# Ubuntu 22.04 failing to progress at "Copying package lists..." with "stdin: Invalid argument"

Tags: boot, uefi, 22.04, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on my HP laptop, as I no longer want to use Debian nor dual boot with Windows.

I am using the ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso image.

I am able to boot this image from two different USBs on an older HP laptop, but not my current HP laptop. So there is no problem with the ISO or the USBs.

I have had boot-related problems with Linux with this laptop in the past, and with its graphics drivers, but I forget the details (I've owned this laptop a fair while now) and in any case they were resolvable.

Secure Boot is disabled. Windows fast-boot is disabled.

My laptop isn't on the list of certified hardware, but then neither is my older HP for which the boot works fine, and which is also a HP ENVY:

https://ubuntu.com/certified/laptops?vendor=HP

https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04951442

**Current HP laptop system**

```
Laptop: HP ENVY - 13-ah0003na
OS: UEFI dual boot Windows 10 and Debian 10 (buster)
CPU: Intel Core i7 8550U @ 1.80GHz, Kaby Lake-U/Y 14nm Technology
RAM: 16.0GB Dual-Channel DDR3 (16-20-20-45)
Motherboard: HP 8482 (U3E1)
Graphics: Intel UH Graphics 620, 2047MB NVIDIA GeForce MX150, SLI disabled
Storage: 476GB Western Digital WDC PC SN520 SDAPNUW-512GB-1006
```

**Attempts**

I've tried loads of things but here's two for an example.

Attempt 1:

Use Rufus 3.20.1929 to mount the image to a 32GB Toshiba USB using a GPT partition scheme, FAT32 file system, 16kb cluster size, quick format, extended label and icon files.

Result:

Works on older HP laptop.

Displayed on current HP laptop (first image is from one attempt, I forget the configuration, and the second and third are from the same attempt):

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kulyg.jpg)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceGnm.jpg)
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtDtX.jpg)

Those errors only came up on two of the attempts but they might be informative so that's why I've picked that one to show an image for.

Attempt 2:

Use balenaEtcher to mount the image to a different 32GB Toshiba USB.

Result:

Works on older HP laptop. Same issue on current laptop.

**Notes**

The number of "stdin: Invalid argument" varies, but there tends to be between 1 and 4 of them. It doesn't always get stuck in the same place.

I think the problem has something to do with the "stdin: Invalid argument" as this doesn't appear on my other laptop. Two AskUbuntu questions come up when searching for it:

questions/1393957/stdin-invalid-argument

questions/1376919/problems-installing-ubuntu-stdin-invalid-argument

The second question has no relevant advice.

In the first, iommu=soft is suggested. I tried this (inserting after "quiet splash") and this didn't help. It gets stuck on "Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set" as usual and will probably lead to the Out Of Memory related errors posted above (I didn't wait).

Putting "nomodeset" between "quiet" and "splash" comes up when people try to fix boot issues sometimes. Didn't help me. Got stuck on something to do with renaming iwlwifi to wlan0, which eventually keeps going and gets stuck at something to do with "HDA Intel PCH Headphone". I didn't wait more than a few minutes, it didn't change.

Starting it with "safe graphics" doesn't help. Starting with safe graphics and deleting "quiet splash" gets stuck at "A start job is running for Wait for udev To Complete Device Initialization". I stopped waiting after 10 minutes.

At some point I tried an MBR partition scheme when mounting. Didn't help.

In the first link using NTFS on the USB is mentioned. I did this with NTFS, GPT scheme, and opted for a DD image when Rufus promoted as opposed to ISO to test multiple different things at once. It froze during boot and restarted. On restart it didn't freeze but got stuck on "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)" which immediately follows the "HDA Intel PCH Headphone" error mentioned earlier. While typing up this question I left this on, and after maybe 15 minutes it carried on outputting messages as if it was about to boot and then stopped on a black screen.

In some places people report "stdin: Invalid argument" being repeated ad nauseum. This is not what happens with me, so their issue is probably different to mine. Boot order is mentioned, but my USB is highest in boot order and starts without me having to do anything so I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Putting "nouveau.modeset=1 nvidia.modeset=0" between "quiet" and "splash" doesn't help.

I haven't tried enabling Legacy Support in the UEFI settings as I don't know what that does, I don't want to mess with my existing dual boot as I need this laptop for work, and doubt it's relevant.

I also haven't tried the OEM install option for the same reason. I need the laptop and would rather enter into a Live USB first.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have any USB devices other than the bootable drive connected? Some HP laptops apparently won't boot Linux properly if you have USB devices connected. Also the "out of memory error" is actually an informational message saying that the Userspace Out-Of-Memory Killer service has been successfully started (so it is the opposite of an error: it's telling you everything is fine). In fact the output you give does not *end* in an error, so I wonder if you just left it would it eventually boot (but slowly)?

Comment: No other devices connected. I will leave a USB in while I wait for answers on the offchance that I just (!) need to wait around 20-30 minutes.

Comment: Also, if you look at Image 3, those three services tried and failed to start, and then tried to start again. I didn't wait more than a few minutes extra as it seemed to be in a loop.

Comment: Tried another "safe graphics" boot minus "quiet splash". "Wait for udev To Complete Device Installation" eventually fails to start. Then those three services eventually fail to start, after about 20-25 minutes, and then it tries to start those three processes again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I had to boot via a USB hub.

Hope this helps someone else!

Voila:

[image: Voila]

Edit: having all kinds of trouble actually booting Ubuntu now. Every solution meets with a new major problem. May stick with Debian after all.

Edit 2: the boot issue persisted across attempts to install Ubuntu, Debian, and Mint. Turns out that, on top of the USB hub solution mentioned, I also needed `acpi=off` when actually booting the system, as this laptop is a trickster god that takes pleasure in punishing its users.